# Importing CSV file in Drupal using Migrate module. Want nodes to be owned by admin

Tags: drupal, import, admin, migrate

When importing using the drush migrate-import command, all nodes created are owned by anonymous. I would like them to be owned by the admin user or some other user.

Answer (score 3):

If you're using the GUI to import by .CSV, you may need a custom script like the one suggested above.

The more flexible way is to use the migrate module(newet version), and set up a migration class and where you perform mappings, do this.

```
<code>
<?php
 $this->addFieldMapping('uid')->defaultValue('1');
?>
</code>
```

The default value of '1' should be the UID of whatever the user you want to be the author.

**Make sure you look at the included beer and wine migration examples the come with the module**

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways to go about this but this is probably the quickest:

1. On the mysql command line, or drush sqlc, find the highest node id before importing:

   SELECT MAX(nid) FROM node;
2. Import your nodes.
3. Find the uid of the user you want to set the owner to.

   SELECT uid FROM user WHERE name = 'Admin';
4. Issue an update query to bulk update the nodes:

   UPDATE node SET uid = x WHERE nid > y;

   Where x = uid of admin user, and y = max nid+1

Comment: The question is about CSV, not SQL!